# CakePHP skipping validation for an input

Tags: php, cakephp

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183240/cakephp-password-confirmation-not-allowing-user-to-submit-registration) for password confirmation, but CakePHP seems to be skipping over my re_password validation settings.

Here's my form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Account'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('re_password', array('type'=>'password', 'label'=>'Re-Enter Password', 'value'=>''));
        echo $this->Form->input('role', array('type' => 'hidden', 'default' => 'user'));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

This is in my User model

```
function equalToField($array, $field) {
    return strcmp($this->data[$this->alias][key($array)], $this->data[$this->alias][$field]) == 0;
}

public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '3'),
            'message' => 'A username with a minimum length of 3 characters is required'
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule'    => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
        'rule'    => array('email'),
        'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address.',
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
            'message' => 'A password with a minimum length of 8 characters is required'
        )
    ),
    're_password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('equalToField', 'password'),
            'message' => 'Passwords do not match'
        )
    )
);
```

An error occurs if the minlength rule was triggered for the password field, but nothing ocurrs for the re_password field

I deleted the equalToField method just to see what would happen. I didn't even get an error so it seems as if re_password isn't even being looked at.

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but when I added an additional rule to the password field regarding re_password, I got the following error: "Undefined index: re_password [APP/Model/User.php"

```
'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
            'rule' => array('equalToField', 're_password'),
            'message' => 'A password with a minimum length of 8 characters is required'
        )
    ),
```

Also, in my UsersController action I printed(this->request->data) and the re_password field is set.

Comment: You did not post your controller code. There is probably the source of the issue. PS: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: @mark Thanks for the suggestion of looking in the controller. I forgot that I had previously hashed the passwords there and then saved. I removed it and now the validation is working properly.

Comment: +35 imaginary reputation to @mark!

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP2 you can use something like this:

```
public $validate = array(
    'password' => array(
        'length' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
            'message' => 'Password should have at least 8 chars.'
        )
    ),
    'password_confirmation' => array(
        'length' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
            'message' => 'Password should have at least 8 chars.'
        ),
        'compare' => array(
            'rule' => array('validate_passwords'),
            'message' => 'Passwords are not same.',
        )
    ),
);

public function validate_passwords() {
    return $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] === $this->data[$this->alias]['password_confirmation'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, Try with this..

```
public $validate = array(
            'password' => array(
                'minLength' => array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength', 4),
                    'message' => 'Password must be at least 4 characters long'
                ),
                'maxLength' => array(
                    'rule' => array('maxLength', 50),
                    'message' => 'Password cannot be longer than 50 characters'
                ),
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Please enter a password'
                )
            ),
           'confirm_password' => array(
                'passwordMatch' => array(
                    'rule' => array('identicalFieldValues', 'password'),
                    'message' => 'The two passwords you entered do not match, please try again'
                ),
                'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                    'message' => 'Please confirm your password by entering it twice'
                )
           )
      );
```